# Trying to run a ruby on rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

```
%table.table-hover{}
%thead
  %tr
    %th Registration NO.
    %th Name
    %th Tier
    %th Email
%tbody
  - @accounts.each do |user|
    %tr{:onclick => "window.location='/accounts/#{user[:id]}';"}
      %td #{user.id}
      %td #{user.givenname}
      - if user.admin?
        %td Admin
      - elsif user.tech?
        %td Technician
      - else
        %td User
      %td #{user.email}
```

This is the code for page, so when you click on a row in the table
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhXYP.png), then it should jump another page which is the details about this row.[detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4eww.png)
And here are my test code.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'accounts' do

context :js => true do

before do
  @testAdmin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
end

describe 'Account Page can' do

  before do
    login_as(@testAdmin, :scope => :account)
    visit '/accounts'
  end

  specify "visit account page" do
    page.find(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr").click
    expect(page).to have_content 'Account: testAdmin'
  end

end

end

end
```

When I run and printed out the page, it appears it's still on the table page, which means it does not jumped to the details page.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `context js: true...` line. Shouldn't it be:
`describe "A description that makes sense", js: true do...` ?

Comment: What driver are you using and do you get any errors in your test? If so - what exactly is the error.

Comment: @Daniel `describe`/`context`/`example_group` are all basically aliases of each other and just exist to allow for more descriptive test writing - although you are correct that it needs a string -  `context "blah", js: true` otherwise the `js: true` part is being taken as the name and not as metadata to trigger driver change

Comment: thx for help, but if i put js => true at "Account page can ", this error, will appear. Cliver::Dependency::NotFound:
            Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole They are indeed aliases. I guess that by not having any string as context I just didn't get what I was reading.
j.fu keep in mind to properly format your code when posting a question/answer. It makes it much easier to "get in context" ;)

Comment: @Daniel thx for the help, i will remember to format my question next time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Daniel, your `context` line doesn't have any description text in it. This means `:js => true` will be taken as the name of the context block and not used as metadata to switch to the JS capable driver. This should have been noticeable from the name of the failed test which would have been something like `accounts {:js=>true} Account Page can visit account page`. To fix you should just need to include descriptive text in the `context` call

```
context "something", js: true
```

or just dump the context block and apply the metadata to whichever of the other blocks makes sense

```
describe 'Account Page can', js: true do
  ...
```

Comment: I did try to put the js => true at "Account page can ", but it will give me this error,    Cliver::Dependency::NotFound:
            Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path.

Comment: @j.fu So you've configured your JS tests to use Poltergeist and you don't have phantomjs installed in system path - You need to fix that - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#installing-phantomjs - You'll want phantomjs 2.1.1 which is the latest stable release - http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did fixed my bug.

Comment: @j.fu You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so your question gets marked as answered